# WPF treeview: "non listed items"

Tags: wpf, treeview

based on my model I want to build a treeview. For me it turns out to be a problem, that only members of a collection can be displayed In a treeview. That means, that I have to create a viewmodel containing a collection which holds all properties of my model.

I want to build a tree like this:

> House
>     Adress
>     Color
>     NumberOfRooms
>     Family
>      Father
>      Mother
>      Daughter
>       Age
>       Hair color
>       Friends
>        ...
>     Pets
>      Dog
>      Mouse

My house model has the property adress, color, numberOfRooms, family and pets. Not all of the are lists, and house itself isnt a list either. So i would have to put those properties in a list of objects to be displayed in a tree like fashion, and then create a hierachical datatemplate for each of those properties. Doing this once is not a big deal, but I have many models to deal with, this just doesnt seem to be the right way...

I know i could make a hierachical datatemplate for the House type, put "house" in the header of an expander, and add some textboxes for each non list list property ... This is just ugly.

Is there any common approach for this kind of datastructure / model ?

Comment: It is only ugly if you make it ugly

Comment: The thing is I would not be able to individually select the properties anymore! Only the items which appear in a list

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that using MultiBinding + Converter is a pretty elegant solution.

Here is a link http://www.hardcodet.net/2008/12/heterogeneous-wpf-treeview